# Match favorite data from db with data coming from api

Tags: kotlin

I have a `mutableListOf` a sealed class.
I am trying to compare the result coming from the api with the ones saved in the db so I can update my UI base on `isSaved` attribute. Here is my code :

```
sealed class MasterList(val type: Type) {

    data class FavoriteList(
        val list: List<Info>
    ): MasterList(Type.FAVORITE)

    data class Child1List(
        val title: String,
        val list: List<Info1>
    ) : MasterList(Type.CHILD_1)

    data class Child2List(
        val title: String,
        val list: List<Info2>
    ) : MasterList(Type.CHILD_2)
}
data class Info(
    val fname: String,
    val lname: String,
    val age: String,
    val address: String
)
data class Info1(
    val fname: String,
    val lname: String,
    val isSaved: Boolean
)
data class Info2(
    val age: String,
    val address: String,
    val isSaved: Boolean
)
enum class Type {
    FAVORITE,
    CHILD_1,
    CHILD_2
}
fun loadInfo(): List<MasterList>? {
    val resultList = mutableListOf<MasterList>()
    val savedResult = MasterList.FavoriteList(localStroage.getAllFavorite())
    val feedResult = api.fetchAllInfo()
    return if (feedResult == null)
        null
    else {
        resultList.add(0, savedResult)
        resultList.addAll(feedResult)
        markSavedInfo(feedResult,savedResult.list)
        // I need to compare my savedResult with feedResult to put isSaved to true if it exist
        return resultList
    }
}
private fun markSavedInfo(feedResult: List<MasterList>, favoriteList: List<Info>) {
    feedResult.forEach {
        when (it.type) {
            Type.CHILD_1 -> {
                (it as MasterList.Child1List).list.forEach {
                    val name = it.fname
                    for (saved in favoriteList) {
                        if (name == saved.fname)
                            println("Result $name")
                    }
                }
            }
            Type.CHILD_2 -> {
                (it as MasterList.Child2List).list.forEach {
                    val age = it.age
                    for (saved in favoriteList) {
                        if (age == saved.age)
                            println("xxx: Result $age")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the best I could do , it's `markSavedInfo` function but I don't think it's the best solution !

Comment: What exactly should the function `markSavedInfo` do? And why are you posting "mocked" code here. If you want review than post your real code. If it's real code then it's not bad but naming is terrible. What is Child, Child1, Info1, fname, lname etc.?